# order of execution in an expression with commas in C++

Tags: c++

It is my understanding that the term `j = i` will be executed before `++i` in the statement

`j = i, ++i;`.

Does the C++ standard guarantee that `j = i` will be executed before `++i` in the loop

`for (auto i = std::next(begin), j = begin; i!= end; j= i, ++i)`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 13):

The comma operator [introduces a sequence point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) and, as such, this behavior is guaranteed by the C++ standard.