# Cleanest way to avoid writing same condition twice

Tags: c++, do-while

Lets say I have a loop that inputs a value from user, and if the value is equal to zero, it breaks.

Is there a way to do this without writing the same condition twice?

for example:

```cpp
int x;

do
{
    std::cin >> x;
    
    if (x)
    {
        //code
    }

} while(x);
```

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably cleanest to write a little function to read the value, and return a boolean to indicate whether you read a non-zero value, then use that function:

```cpp
bool read(int &x) { 
    std::cin >> x;
    return std::cin && (x != 0);
}

while (read(x)) {
    // code to process x
}
```

Comment: Yup, clean and well-defined behaviour in all C++ standards. Note that `read` would probably be in an anonymous namespace or similar construct.

Answer (score 1):

The most laconic way (and note how it tests the integrity of the input stream) is

```
while (int x; std::cin >> x && x){
    // code
}
```

---

Another approach, which gives you a bit more scope for introducing code for the fail condition, is

```
for (;;){ // infinite loop idiom
    int x;
    if (std::cin >> x && x){
        // code
        continue; // i.e. go round again
    }
    // ToDo - code here?
    break;
};
```

is one way. This is not to everyone's taste although the `break;` before the end of the loop body gives some comfort that the loop is not *really* infinite.

It also has the advantage that the scope of `x` is not leaked to the outer scope.

Comment: `while (true)` is a much more obvious infinite loop.

Comment: @user673679: Not really, compilers emit warnings for that, and it's bad form to suppress them. `for(;;)` is idiomatic C and C++.

Comment: What compiler? You felt the need to write a comment for your loop, which shows it's not obvious.

Comment: @user673679: It's not obvious to the youngsters coming out of MIT - but it is obvious to folk who grew up programming in the formative years of C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the code exactly as you described it with words it get's simpler:

```
int x;

while(std::cin >> x) // I have a loop that inputs a value from user, and ...
{
    if(x == 0)       // if the value is equal to zero, ...
    {
        break;       // it breaks.
    }

    // do something with x ...
}
```

The reason for having `std::cin >> x;` as condition is to stop reading when invalid input is entered or the stream ends.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way looks really clean, but I know a lot of programmers don't like to use "break", including my teacher (don't know why). I am looking for a way without it.

Comment: `while(int x; std::cin >> x)` would be even more beautiful.

Comment: @אמיריפה: time for you to convince your teacher of the merits of `break`.

Comment: Yes, breaks should be avoided. They are actually unconditional jumps (which we all know are bad since 1968) and it will force you to surround it with a condition, which is not so bad, but many-many times it just gives you an extra test case to test or an extra thing to worry.

Comment: @FlorinC.: I disagree with this strict interpretation of goto's considered harmful. Early loop exits are clean. In some cases, cascaded exits are just better than awfully nested conditions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: that is the title of the article, don't take it literally. Yes indeed, there are some cases when early exits are better. However, the point is: avoid it when you can and in this case it can.

Answer (score 0):

Verbatim "a loop that inputs a value from user, and if the value is equal to zero, it breaks."

```
while (true)
{
  std::cin >> x;
  if (x == 0)
    break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than bunging everything into the loop condition.

Comment: @user673679: And you are willing to suppress compiler warnings. Although I like this answer as it is such a literal translation of what you want to do, and therefore readable.

Comment: Note of course that the behaviour is undefined if `std::cin >> x` fails prior to C++11, as you have a subsequent read of an uninitialised `x`. My way (forgive the plug) using `&&` (which is sequenced and short-circuit) works in all standards. Although of course my declaration within the conditional is C++17 onwards only.

Comment: I don't want to clutter the answer with considerations on `cin` failures.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int x;
while (std::cin >> x, x) {
    std::cout << x*5 << std::endl;
}
```

No ifs, no breaks, the x is already evaluated to be non-zero by the while condition.

Comment: Did you test this code? ... If a `0` is entered, it doesn't end the loop.

Comment: @Damien: thanks for pointing it out. i have tested it on https://code.sololearn.com/ which stops the program when the input ends. corrected it

Comment: It doesn't work for me, doesn't detect that input ends. It works with `while (std::cin >> x && x)`

Comment: `std::cin >> x, x` is a poor cousin to `std::cin >> x && x` as the former is a read of uninitialised `x` (undefined behaviour) in older C++ standards.

Comment: Really? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773412/order-of-execution-in-an-expression-with-commas-in-c